# Bootstrap Modal not working with asp.net web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

So, I have a web form in asp.net. On that web form, there is a GridView. When the user clicks the view details on gridview, I want a modal popup to show the list of stores in that category. I have been trying different stuff but the modal does not show up. Below is my code for front end:

```
            <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>

            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">

                <ContentTemplate>

                    <div id="DetailsModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">

                        <div class="modal-dialog">

                            <div class="modal-content">

                                <div class="modal-header">
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblHead" runat="server" Text="List of stores:" CssClass="h4"></asp:Label>
                                </div>

                                <div class="modal-body">

                                    <asp:Table ID="tblJobs" runat="server" CssClass="tblStoresView" GridLines="Both" CellPadding="6" CellSpacing="6" Visible="False">
                                        <asp:TableRow runat="server">

                                            <asp:TableCell runat="server">
                                                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Store Name"></asp:Label>
                                            </asp:TableCell>

                                            <asp:TableCell runat="server">
                                                <asp:Label ID="lblPost" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
                                            </asp:TableCell>

                                        </asp:TableRow>

                                        <asp:TableRow runat="server">

                                            <asp:TableCell runat="server">
                                                <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Floor"></asp:Label>
                                            </asp:TableCell>

                                        </asp:TableRow>

                                        <asp:TableRow runat="server">

                                            <asp:TableCell runat="server">
                                                <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text="Store number"></asp:Label>
                                            </asp:TableCell>

                                            <asp:TableCell runat="server">
                                                <asp:Label ID="lblType" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
                                            </asp:TableCell>

                                        </asp:TableRow>

                                </asp:Table>

                                </div>

                                <div class="modal-footer">
                                    <asp:Button ID="BtnView" CssClass="button" runat="server" Text="View" Visible="False" OnClick="BtnView_Click" />
                                </div>

                            </div>

                        </div>

                    </div>

                </ContentTemplate>

            </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

I am trying to view the modal on grid's selectindexchanged event. The code I am using is as follows:

```
protected void gridStores_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            tblStores.Visible = true;
            BtnView.Visible = true;
            GridViewRow row = gridStores.SelectedRow;

            conn = new SqlConnection();
            conn.ConnectionString = connString;
            sqlcmd = conn.CreateCommand();

            string query = "select * from [stores] where cat = @cat";

            sqlcmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
            sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cat", row.Cells[1].Text);

                conn.Open();

                da = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlcmd);
                ds = new DataSet();
                da.Fill(ds, "StoresProject");
                dt = ds.Tables[0];

                foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
                {
                    lblName.Text = dr["store name"].ToString();
                    lblFloow.Text = dr["floor"].ToString();
                    lblNumber.Text = dr["store number"].ToString();

                }
        }
```

Can someone please tell me why the modal popup is not showing up? What am i doing wrong? Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks!

**UPDATE:** I tried to display the modal without any grid and backend C# code, by using the simple template from W3Schools. The modal still does not popup at all.

Comment: Have you looked at your browser's dev-tools console?

Comment: Also, why on earth are you using WebForms in 2020? And you need to correctly dispose of your `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand` objects (use a `using()` block). Finally, you should use `SqlDataReader` instead of `SqlDataAdapter` - there's no need to use a `DataSet` for this.

Comment: What would you suggest instead of webforms? @Dai 
And can you please tell me what I am doing wrong and how can I make the modal to popup? I have to submit this project.

Comment: You need to use javascript to show the modal:   $('#myModal').modal('show').    Since you are using WebForms, use [ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.scriptmanager.registerstartupscript?view=netframework-4.8) to call the javascript from the SelectedIndexChanged event

Comment: Agree with previous comments though, WebForms are pretty outdated at this point. You probably want to be looking at Razor Pages in .NET Core or similar. Also look at using an ORM like [Entity Framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/) vs using ADO.NET directly

Comment: @GlynnHurrell I tried using the ScriptManager.RegusterStartupScript but it did not work either.

Comment: @Dai Yes I tried the browser's dev tools. I also tried typing `$('#DetailsModal').modal();` in the console window and the modal did show up correctly. But I dont see any errors in the browser's dev tools window either.

Comment: @Dai Also, if I remove the classes "modal fade" from the div that contains the modal, the modal content shows up at bottom as part of the page but looks the same way like the modal dialog box.

Comment: Keep your Grid view inside the Update panel and keep your modal outside the update panel.

Comment: @noobprogrammer i'll try that and let you know.

Comment: @noobprogrammer that did not work either.

Comment: @AtifAli did you build your project properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I solved my problem. It occurred to me that if I enter `$(#DetailsModal).modal()` in the console window of chrome, the modal appears. So I should try calling it the same way in my site.

So, I wrote a javascript function at the end of my page:

```
<script>

        function openModal(){
        $('#DetailsModal').modal();
        }

    </script>
```

And in the code-behind I called by using:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.GetType(), "script", "openModal();", true);
```

And then after that when I tried opening the modal, it appeared correctly with the correct data.

Thanks to everyone who took time out of their schedule to give suggestions.